# Integrate $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x(1+x^2)^2} dx$ with contour integral

Tags: integration, contour-integration, complex-integration, residue-calculus, cauchy-integral-formula

How to integrate $$I=\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x(1+x^2)^2}dx$$ using contour integration?

Since, it is even,

$$I=0.5*\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x(1+x^2)^2}dx$$

$$I=-0.25i(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{ix}}{{x(1+x^2)^2}}dx-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-ix}}{{x(1+x^2)^2}}dx)$$

For second term,

$x \rightarrow -x$

$$\implies I=-0.25i(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{ix}}{{x(1+x^2)^2}}dx+\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{ix}}{{x(1+x^2)^2}}dx)$$

$$\implies I=-0.5i\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{ix}}{{x(1+x^2)^2}}dx$$

$$I=\frac{1}{2i}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{ix}}{x(1+x^2)^2}dx$$

$$I=\frac{1}{2i}(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{ix}}{x}dx-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{xe^{ix}}{1+x^2}dx-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{xe^{ix}}{(1+x^2)^2}dx)$$

$$I=\frac{1}{2i}(-\pi i)-\frac{1}{2i}*2\pi i*\frac{ie^{-1}}{2i}-\frac{1}{2i}*2\pi i*\frac{e^{-1}}{4}$$

$$I=\frac{-\pi }{2}-\frac{\pi e^{-1}}{2}-\frac{\pi e^{-1}}{4}$$
$$I=-\frac{\pi}{2}(1+\frac{3e^{-1}}{2})$$

But, the answer is $\frac{\pi}{2}(1-\frac{3}{2e})$. Where am I committing a mistake?

Comment: In order to avoid divergences, use $\displaystyle\sin\left(x\right) = \Im\left(\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}x} - 1\right)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can evaluate the integral of interest by writing ($\varepsilon>0$ and $R>1$)

$$\begin{align}
\oint_{C}\frac{e^{iz}}{z(1+z^2)^2}\,dz&=\int_{-R}^{-\epsilon}\frac{e^{ix}}{x(1+x^2)^2}\,dx+\int_\pi^0 \frac{e^{i\varepsilon e^{i\phi}}}{\varepsilon e^{i\phi}\left(1+\varepsilon^2 e^{i2\phi}\right)^2}\,i\varepsilon e^{i\phi}\,d\phi\\\\
& +\int_{\varepsilon}^R \frac{e^{ix}}{x(1+x^2)^2}\,dx+\int_0^\pi \frac{e^{iR e^{i\phi}}}{R e^{i\phi}\left(1+R^2 e^{i2\phi}\right)^2}\,iR e^{i\phi}\,d\phi
\end{align}$$

Let $R\to \infty$, $\varepsilon\to0$, take the imaginary part, and set the integral equal to $i2\pi$ times the the residue of $\frac{e^{iz}}{z(1+z^2)^2}$ at $z= i$ (This remedies the second issue.) to find the result.

Can you finish?

---

If one wishes to proceed using partial fraction expansion, then I would suggest the following.  First, we use partial fraction expansion to write the integral $I=\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x(1+x^2)^2}\,dx$ as

$$\begin{align}
I&=\frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x(1+x^2)^2}\,dx\\\\
&=\frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(\frac{\sin(x)}{x}-\frac{x\sin(x)}{1+x^2}-\frac{x\sin(x)}{(1+x^2)^2}\right)\,dx\tag1
\end{align}$$

Then, we can evaluate each of the three integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$ using contour integration.

Using the residue theorem, we have

$$\begin{align}
0&=\oint_{C}\frac{e^{iz}}{z}\,dz\\\\
&=\int_{-R}^\varepsilon \frac{e^{ix}}{x}\,dx+\int_\pi^0 \frac{e^{i\varepsilon e^{i\phi}}}{\varepsilon e^{i\phi}}\,i\varepsilon e^{i\phi}\,d\phi\\\\
&+\int_\varepsilon^R \frac{e^{ix}}{x}\,dx+\int_\pi^0 \frac{e^{i R e^{i\phi}}}{R e^{i\phi}}\,iR e^{i\phi}\,d\phi\tag 2
\end{align}$$

Letting $R\to \infty$, $\varepsilon\to0$, and taking the imaginary part of $(2)$, we find that

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x}\,dx=\pi\tag3$$

Next, we write

$$\begin{align}
2\pi i \left(\frac{ie^{-1}}{i2}\right)&=\oint_{C}\frac{ze^{iz}}{1+z^2}\,dz\\\\
&=\int_{-R}^R \frac{xe^{ix}}{1+x^2}\,dx+\int_0^\pi \frac{R e^{i\phi} e^{i R e^{i\phi}}}{1+R^2 e^{i2\phi}}\,iR e^{i\phi}\,d\phi\tag 4
\end{align}$$

Letting $R\to \infty$ and taking the imaginary part of $(4)$ reveals

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x\sin(x)}{1+x^2}\,dx=\frac{\pi}{e}\tag5$$

Similarly, we find that

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x\sin(x)}{(1+x^2)^2}\,dx=\frac{\pi}{2e}\tag6$$

Using $(3)$, $(5)$, and $(6)$ in $(1)$ yields that coveted result

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x(1+x^2)^2}\,dx=\frac\pi2 \left(1-\frac3{2e}\right)$$

Comment: But I did get rid of the singularity by taking partial fractions. The first term, $\frac{e^{ix}}{x}$ has the singularity and the other two terms don't. So, for the first term, I've deformed the contour and got the result as $-\pi i$. Is there anything wrong in the way I did?

Comment: The way you've written things is not correct.  In addition, how did you account for the residues at $\pm i$.

Comment: I've taken the contour only along the top half of the Argand plane; so only one pole i.e., $x=i$

Comment: Again, the way you've written thing is not correct.  Have a look at my solution and see if you have any questions.  For example $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{xe^{ix}}{1+x^2}\,dx$ diverges.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I think I realised my mistake now. $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{ix}}{x}dx=i\pi$ and NOT $-i\pi$.

Comment: You're welcome.  I've added a second section which provides a rigorous approach to the one you had followed.

Comment: @ Mark Viola You might wish to see a simpler approach in my answer.

Comment: @dr.wolfganghintze I am more than familiar with Feyman's trick.  The intent of this exercise was to answer the OP's question as to what part of the development was flawed.  Going back to simplifying, we need not even use contour integration, but rather can identify an ODE for the integral of interest augmented with a parameter.  Solution to the ODE is trivial.

Comment: @Mark Viola You might have read the beginning of my contribution "This is an extended comment which shows how to cirvcumvent the main difficulty in attacking the integral directly by contour integration". Also I like your interesting statement that you are "more than familiar" with something (here what you call the "Feynman Trick"). And thanks for suggesting additional means of simplification which shows that you follow the intention of my contribution.

Answer (score 2):

In order to you use contour integral you can use residues.

In fact let's set : $f(z) \triangleq \dfrac{e^{izt}}{z(z^2+1)^2}$

So the singularities of $f$ are $0$, $-i$ , $i$ . Let's make around $i$. Take a contour $C$ such $i$ is included in (hemi circle $C_1$ is the small one with radius $r$, and quarter circle $C_2$ is the big one with radius  $R-r$) up the hemi circle in sort of elevating it from the absciss from more than $1$ unit.

$$  \int_C f(z) = \sum_p 2\pi*ires(f,p)$$

So $$ \int_C f(z) = \int_r^R f(z) dz + \int_{-r}^{-R}{f(z)}dz + \int_{C1} f(z) dz + \int_{C2} f(z) dz = res(f,i)
 $$
[Quarter circle contour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d30PE.png)

Then make tend $r$ and $R$ respectly to their values $ 0 $ infinity.

Answer (score 2):

This is an extended comment which shows how to cirvcumvent the main difficulty in attacking the integral directly by contour integration as in this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3596146/198592.  It is a kind of "wrapping" which renders the singularity innocent.

The integral to be solved is

$$i = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin (x)}{x} \frac{1}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2}\,dx\tag{1}$$

The trick is to write

$$\frac{\sin (x)}{x}=\frac{1}{2} \int_{-1 }^{1 } \exp (-i t x) \, dt\tag{2}$$

Inserting this and doing the $x$-integration (by straightforward contour integration, possibly taking into account the remarks in the discussion) gives

$$\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{\exp (-i t x)}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2} \, dx=\frac{1}{2} \pi  e^{-\left| t\right| } (\left| t\right| +1)\tag{3}$$

so that from the sub sequenty $t$-integral we get finally

$$i = \frac{\pi}{4}\int_{-1}^{1 }  e^{-\left| t\right| } (\left| t\right| +1)  \, dt
\\=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{0}^1 e^{-t } ( t +1) \, dt
\\=\pi  \left(1-\frac{3}{2 e}\right)\simeq 1.4080016313205$$

**Discussion**

The calculation of the integral $(3)$ can be simplified observing that

$$ \frac{1}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2}=-\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{da}\frac{1}{\left(x^2+a^2\right)}|_{a\to 1}$$

so that it is sufficient to calculate

$$\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{\exp (-i t x)}{\left(x^2+a^2\right)} \, dx$$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
I & =
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\sin\pars{x} \over x\pars{1 + x^{2}}^{2}}\,\dd x =
{1 \over 2}\,\Im\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\expo{\ic x} - 1 \over
x\pars{x - \ic}^{2}\pars{x + \ic}^{2}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 2}\,\Im\braces{2\pi\ic \lim_{\large x\ \to\ \ic}\,
\totald{}{x}\bracks{\expo{\ic x} - 1 \over x\pars{x + \ic}^{2}}}
\\[5mm] & =
\pi\,\Re\braces{\lim_{\large x\ \to\ \ic}\,
\bracks{\ic\expo{\ic x}\pars{x^{2} + 4\ic x - 1} + 3x + \ic \over
x^{2}\pars{x + \ic}^{3}}}
\\[5mm] & =
\bbx{\pi\pars{{1 \over 2} - {3 \over 4\expo{}}}}\
\approx\ 0.7040
\end{align}